# How to scale MapPolyline while zooming in/out, the same as MapRoute?

Tags: android, here-api

I am developing HERE Android application with the HERE Android SDK. I am having a MapRoute object as well as a MapPolyline. The issue is that when the map is zoomed in the polyline appears to be thiner that the MapRoute itself, while when the map is zoomed out the plyline appears to be thicker that the MapRoute. I tam using setPerspectiveEnabled(true) on the polyline (https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.15/api_reference_java/index.html?com%2Fhere%2Fandroid%2Fmpa%2Fmapping%2FMapPolyline.html) and set different polyline width, but the result is still the same. In the images the polyline is the purple line, the mapRoute is the blue line.

[zoom in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRLFc.png)

[zoom out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JxQl.png)

Here is a code snippet:

```
private final Map map; 
private MapPolyline routeBeginning;

@Override
public void addRouteBeginning(final GeoPolyline geoPolyline) {
    MapPolyline mapPolyline = new MapPolyline(geoPolyline);

    mapPolyline.setLineColor(INavigationView.ROUTE_TO_START_COLOR);
    mapPolyline.setLineWidth(INavigationView.ROUTE_TO_START_LINE_WIDTH);
    mapPolyline.setOverlayType(MapOverlayType.ROAD_OVERLAY);
    mapPolyline.setPerspectiveEnabled(true);
        
map.addMapObject(mapPolyline);
    routeBeginning = mapPolyline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic with PerspectiveEnabled looks reasonable. Can you try to check using getwidth(), getOutlineWidth() and getShadowWidth() what exactly polyline width and shadow width returning in both zoom-in and out gestures ? are these not actually changing when the map is tilted or both the shadow and width need to be fixed for your use case ? would be helpful if code snippet could be shared.

Comment: Thanks for te response. I tried checking  getwidth(), getOutlineWidth() and getShadowWidth(), but all of them remained unchanged while zooming in/out as well as tilting the map.I also tried not setting lineWidth(), but that resulted in really thin polyline. I added code snippet to the main post.